# How to wait until query finishes to load Collection View

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, parse-platform

I have a project where I'm performing a Parse query on the viewDidLoad.

With the results of the query I create an (images) array and populate a grid (CollectionView) with the elements from the array.

The overall result is working as expected, the problem is that the first time the query takes longer to execute than the collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: method to be invoked so when the view loads I get a empty screen.

I have implemented the refreshControl so when I refresh everything is there and it works as expected.  The problem is that first time.

How could I make my app wait until the query is done before it attempts to load the cells?

Can I put that [self queryForGrid]; inside a block and put some kinf of activity indicator to make the user know he must wait?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced,

Juan.

Answer (score 1):

Parse has a number of different methods to fetch or refresh an object which take a completion handler parameter.  The block passed in as the completion handler will be invoked when the fetch/refresh is complete.  Show your view controller from that block.  (Also, you might want to display an activity indicator of some sort before you start the fetch and stop/hide the activity indicator in the completion handler as well).

Comment: Those methods you mention work great for the PFQueryTableViewController class and I'm actually using them but there is nothing similar for the UICollectionViewController.